# Best practices with poll / select and writefds

Tags: c, select

Most of examples for `select()` and `poll()` works in a way similar to this:

```
int activity = select(FD_SETSIZE, &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);
//...
for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++){
    int sd = client_socket[i];
    if (FD_ISSET(sd , &readfds)){
        int len = read(sd , buffer, 1024);
        if (len == 0){
            // disconnect
        }
        // echo server, send the data back
        send(sd , buffer , len , 0 );
    }
}
```

The problem I see with this code is - why we think / expect this `send()` call will not block?

Even if we do the socket non blocking, then `send()` will not block, but will send part of the data or even nothing.

May be I am wrong, but I think I need to have array of strings and to use `writefds` until data is sent etc.

Is there any good examples / practices for this?

Comment: If you're using select/poll you're going to need to be non-blocking. Then whether the read and send handles all or some of the data depends on what protocol is being used. Is this a specific protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about worrying that `send()` will block, because it can.

The usual solution is to set the socket mode to non-blocking.  Then, each time you call `send()`, check if:

1. not all data was sent; or
2. `errno` to see if it is `EGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.

If either of those things happen, then the system's socket buffer is full and you will need to store your data somewhere while "waiting" until the kernel sends some data and frees up space in the system's socket buffer.

Now, that's where you add the socket to the `writefds` array passed to `select()` to ask the system to let you know when the socket becomes writable again.  When this socket is returned by `select()`, you should try sending your data again.  If any extra data has queued up in the meantime, try to send that as well.  If you can send all your data, remove the socket from the `writefds` array (or it will be returned on each call to `select()`).

Comment: As an additional note send() can send less data than you request it to send(Assuming TCP or a similar stream based socket), so you also need to track how much has been sent - and not simply re-send an entire buffer - nor assume it's all sent if send() indicates success.

Comment: so I basically need array of strings, where I will store the data to be send and to update the string after part of it is sent for example with memmove() ?

Comment: one more related question, if I set bit in readfds or writefds, without really need it, this can cause ONLY performance penalty, correct?

Comment: @nos: Yes, but `send()` doesn't send anything when `EAGAIN` is returned.  @Nick: correct, although I wouldn't recommend `memmove()` if you want very high performance.  In a typical server, that performance penalty is major.  It's very important to manage the `readfds` and `writefds` arrays correctly.

Comment: @AndréCaron Sure, but that's just a special case of you sending 0 bytes. the send() call could send anything from 1 up to and including the given length of bytes, It's not just the case of send() giving EAGAIN , but also the case when send() returns < 'length', that you have to store the (remaining) data somewhere and send it later when select() indicates you can send

Comment: @nos Sorry, misunderstood your original comment :-)  You're absolutely right, I'll update the answer!

Comment: thanks all. I said memmove() because is easiest way to explain with single word.